# At what aspect ratio does orientation landscape become orientation portrait?

Tags: css, browser, responsive-design, media-queries

I've noticed that media queries do a terrible job at targeting "only tablets" or "only phones" even with `orientation: portrait` or `orientation: landscape` because you still target desktop browsers, depending on how the browser's width or height which can change at any user's discretion.

At what point does the desktop browser return true for `orientation: portrait` on a media query? I'm assuming it changes based on aspect-ratio.

Comment: CSS orientation detection logic just checks whether window height is  > window width (`height > width`), if true then portrait mode is enabled for css media query to work. similarly when width is greater than height (`width > height`), than landscape.  obviously this logic wont work all the time, hence extra care need to be taken when handling orientation changes via CSS.